# How to find a pareto optimal solution in a smart way (3 variables)

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$\max\left( { 3x }_{ 1 }+4{ x }_{ 2 }+2{ x }_{ 3 } \right)  $

${ x }^2_{ 1 }+{ x }^2_{ 2 }+{ x }^2_{ 3 }\le 1 $

${ x }_{ i }\ge 0 $

I have to find a **Pareto Optimal solution**, but I can't solve this by making calculus (Lagrangian function). 
So Is there a smart way to do this?

I know the objective function is a plane, and the constraint is a sphere. But is very difficult to find where the plane intersect the sphere

Comment: what is the $x^i$ ? the i , especially. it sounds to be $x_i$

Comment: why you cant solve it by lagrange ?

Comment: It ask me to find a pareto optimal solution. I can resolve by lagrange because I have just 3 minutes to do this.

Comment: First please say to me what is that i ? !

Comment: it highly depends on objective function convexity/concavity

Comment: Just all variables are positive or zero.

Comment: @Cardinal What do you mean? In which way if the objective function is Convex could help me?

Comment: if it is concave then the second condition is idle and if it is convex the solution is 0 0 0

Comment: In this case the objective function is linear, so the optimal solution is one where $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 =1$. Finally, you'd like to have as much "weight" on the point $x_2$ as possible...

Comment: oh sorry, i mixed up with that i :|

Comment: Yair Zick is true

Comment: @YairZick you mean is simply $x_i= sqrt(1/3) $ ?

Comment: That's not optimal. It's pretty fast to do with Lagrange multipliers (but that varies I guess).

Comment: Why is the answer not just (0,1,0)? Am I misunderstanding something? The constraint he wrote down isn't a sphere...

Comment: It's not a sphere, it's the positive octant of the 3d sphere

Comment: Since the optimization target is linear, the optimal solution is to be found on $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1$. Using Lagrange's method we write 
$L(x_1,x_2,x_3,\lambda) = 3x_1 + 4x_2 + 2x_3 - \lambda(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 - 1)$ and derive $L$ on all parameters. 
$\partial L/\partial x_1 = 3 - 2\lambda x_1; \partial L/\partial x_2 = 4 - 2\lambda x_2; \partial L\partial x_3 = 2 - 2\lambda$. Setting all partial derivatives to 0 and solving you get $x_1 = \frac{3}{\sqrt 29},x_2 = \frac{4}{\sqrt 29}, x_3 = \frac{2}{\sqrt 29}$.

Comment: Why does everyone keep writing $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \leq 1$ when his question asks $x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 1$? I'm pretty sure the answer is just $(0,1,0)$...

Comment: Because the orignal question had it, and then he changed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), we have
$$\begin{align}(3x_1+4x_2+2x_3)^2&\leq (3^2+4^2+2^2)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)=29(1) \\\Rightarrow 3x_1+4x_2+2x_3&\leq\sqrt{29}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

You can easily solve this using the Lagrange multiplier method but a smarter way to do this would be as follows.

The question seems to me like an optimisation problem regarding utilisation maximisation of a consumer with finite income. Consider a consumer which is faced to buy three different products with amounts ($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$) and prices (1, 1, 1). If the utility function is described as

f($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$)= 3$x_1$+4$x_2$+2$x_3$

and the income of the consumer is 1 unit, then the problem is identical to the one stated above.

The optimal solution is reached for

($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$)= (0, 1, 0)

since the marginal utility is constant for all variables and largest for $x_2$.

The way described here is only another way to say that the problem is convex ( even linear ) and **the** optimum is reached on the boundary.

I hope I' m not wrong and it has helped. For further research on this type of specific problem in economics you can start by [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_good) and continue with any undergraduate microeconomics book, the whole theory is related to such problems.

Comment: Deniz Sargun, this is clearly suboptimal (note that the value of this solution is 4, whereas setting the point $x_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ yields $9/\sqrt{3}$...

Comment: But your answer is not in the constraint set, it is not affordable by the consumer. The domain is not a sphere but a convex polyhedron.

Comment: Oh, it's because in the original post the constraint was $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 \le 1$; now I see that the asker changed it to $x_1 + x_2 +x_3 \le 1$, in which case your answer is obviously correct.

Answer (score 1):

since we have maximization problem and the objective is linear, the second condition is idle:

The refined version of the problem :

$
\min-(3x_1 + 4x_2 +2x_3)
$

$
S.j\ \ ||x_i ||_2 <=1
$

Answer:

Lagrange :
$
-(3x_1 + 4x_2 +2x_3)-\lambda (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)
$

take derivatives and ...
But if you want a shortcut in $4$ options-based tests, check the the options one-by-one what option has norm $\leq 1$ and biggest value of objective function, simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry about the types, my Latex and English is terrible